# CocoaPod - threw error when version is not set

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In a `podfile` you can set a version code or not. For example it looks like this:

```
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'Alamofire', '4.6.0'
```

Can I define a rule in cocoaPod that only pods with a version are accepted?

**The story behind**

I'm working a lot with buildscripts and different build agents which always execute a `pod update`.

In a stupid moment I forgot to set a version number. Some day the pod releases a new version that compiles but the logic was broken. The result was that I built apps that crashed. My thought is now to threw an error in `pod install` or `pod update` when there is an pod without a version number. On Google I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution by CocoaPods, but I wrote my own shell script. I'm quite sure that a regex pro is laughing about, but it works for me.

```
grep "\bpod ['\"]\w*['\"]$" Podfile > pods_without_version.txt
pods_without_version=$(grep -c ^ pods_without_version.txt)
count=$(grep -c ^ pods_without_version.txt)

if [ $count != 0 ]; then
   echo "Error - $count Pod(s) without versions:"
   cat pods_without_version.txt
fi
```

Filter all pods which begin with `pod`, are surrounded with `"` or `'` and haven't nothing behind the second `'`,`"`

Example Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
 pod 'Alamofire', '4.6.0'
 pod "GoogleMaps"
 pod 'GooglePlaces'
end

target 'MyAppProject' do
 shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppProjectTests' do
 inherit! :search_paths
 shared_pods
end
```

Output

```
Error - 2 Pod(s) without versions:
pod "GoogleMaps"
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```